# appending a row converts string to date instead of leaving it as string

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that appends a row. in the row there is one value which is a string that contain a year and its quarter in the following format: year-quarter (e.g. 2014-3). Until today I had no problem but suddenly it turns it into a date.

I tried using copy format of the above row which I have set to plain text but it doesn't work.

Here's my test code as the original script is way too long:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = s.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = s.getLastColumn()
  s.insertRowsAfter(lastRow, 1);
  // copying previous row format
  s.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, lastColumn).copyFormatToRange(s, 1, lastColumn, lastRow+1, lastRow+1);
  var content = ['Shipping','2014-3'];
  s.appendRow(content);
}
```

The code is embedded in the following spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TitZsXOssqybMqAMU9osdpAEH-utvjkEa4ZKBxuinUo/edit?usp=sharing

appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the original range has the format `Automatic`, change it to String with `setNumberFormat("@STRING@")` before copying the text.

Comment: That's why I was trying to use copyFormatToRange but it doesn't seem to work... However, I just tried your suggestion and it didn't work. The only changed was that the alignment has changed to the right.

Comment: Append row, change the format of that Row, then paste values.

Comment: That's what I did. insertRowsAfter then change the format using copyFormatToRange then appendRow... Am I missing something here? Using setNumberFormat("@STRING@") didn't work either.

Comment: Here it worked, setting as `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("A1").setValue("2014-3");` gives a Date, but `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("A1").setNumberFormat("@STRING@").setValue("2014-3");` generates a String...

Comment: Thanks for that! It's a work around. But please, if you know of a more elegant way please let me know as I have that in many places and some of the row entry needs to be numbers. As at the function I don't know what needs to be string or not then the above is not sustainable. I will need to find a more generic solution in the next few days otherwise other code will be broken. Thanks again!

Comment: You'll have to manually check and set the dates as String, and the numbers as numbers, you can set the whole range at once with [setNumberFormats()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormats(Object)), and feed it an array.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an apostrophe before the string that looks like a date, like this:

```
  var content = ["Shipping","'2014-3"];
  s.appendRow(content);
```

Comment: Thank you, very useful if you don't want to execute getRange() and only appendRow()